# Which filter/action should I use to serve content for "virtual" files

Tags: plugins, 404-error, pre-get-posts

I'm working on a plugin for a custom post type whose real content is cached in a redis database.

When a user requests http://my-site/some-post my plugin retrieves the content from redis and returs it.

Now I need to serve the post child assets, ie a request to http://my-site/some-post/picture.jpg or http://my-site/some-post/subdir/media.mp3 should also be retrieved by the plugin from redis however I'm having a hard time to figure out how to handle those content in wordpress since they do not really exists in a directory. Wordpress always returns a 404.

Which filters or actions can I use to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I think the earliest actions you can hook are `muplugins_loaded` and `plugins_loaded`. `muplugins_loaded` will only fire for [Must Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

Some `plugins_loaded` pseudo-code:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpd_plugin_routes' );
function wpd_plugin_routes() {
    if( is_a_virtual_file() ){
        serve_file();
        exit;
    }
}
```

If you want the full WordPress environment, plugins, theme, and authenticated user, right before WordPress parses the request, you've got the `do_parse_request` filter:

```
add_filter( 'do_parse_request', 'wpd_do_parse_request', 1, 3 );
function wpd_do_parse_request( $continue, WP $wp, $extra_query_vars ){
    // do something and halt execution, or
    return $continue; // true by default, meaning continue parsing the request
}
```

If you want all of the above *after* WordPress parses the request, you've got the `parse_request` action. Here you can alter the main query vars:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_parse_request_thing' );
function wpd_parse_request_thing( $query ) {
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['pagename'] ) ){
        if( 'some-page' == $query->query_vars['pagename'] ){
            $query->query_vars['pagename'] = 'some-other-page';
        }
    }
}
```

The last action right before the template is loaded is `template_redirect`. Here all of the `is_` conditionals work:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpd_page_template_redirect' );
function wpd_page_template_redirect() {
    if( is_404() ) {
        // do something
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such concise and yet complete answer !! The do_parse_request did the trick!